# Functions with pointer to pointer and strcpy

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void Get_Text(char *string);
void Get_Text_Double(char **string);
void String_Copy(char *string);

int main(void) {
    char *name = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    char *name2 = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    char *name3 = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));

    Get_Text(name);
    printf("\n%s\n", name);

    Get_Text_Double(&name2);
    printf("\n%s\n", name2);

    String_Copy(name3);
    printf("\n%s\n", name3);

    return 0;
}

void Get_Text(char *string) {
    string = "test";
}

void Get_Text_Double(char **string) {
    *string = "test2";
}

void String_Copy(char *string) {
    strcpy(string, "test3");
}
```

In the above code, why do the `Get_Text_Double` and `String_Copy` functions work and the `Get_Text` function does not?

Also why does the `String_Copy` function work only with a single pointer instead of a double pointer like `Get_Text_Double`?

Comment: we don't use '=' operator to assign a string in c.

Comment: @NeoR then why does the function `Get_Text_Double` work with the `=` operator?

Comment: I think Weather Vane's answer clarifies that doubt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Get_Text` function does not work, because it only changes the *copy* of the pointer that was passed to it. After the function exits, it is lost. The `=` operator cannot copy a string anyway, only the value of the pointer. And so the line

```
printf("\n%s\n", name);
```

causes *undefined behaviour* because the memory allocated to `name` has not been initialised.

In the next function `Get_Text_Double` the *location* of the pointer was passed. This is replaced by a pointer to a string literal, overwriting the pointer that was obtained from `malloc`. So it will now not be possible to `free(name2)`.

In the last function `String_Copy` the library function `strcpy` was used to copy the string literal into the memory that was obtained for `name3`.

The last function is the only one of the three, that actually copies a string into the memory provided. The other two only copy the pointer to a string, being lost in the first example.

**Edit.**

In the third case with a single `*`, a pointer is passed - `name3` which is pointing to allocated memory. That is passed to `strcpy`, which copies the string literal to that memory being pointed to.

But the second function with `**` is passed a *pointer to a pointer*, so instead of being passed the address of the allocated memory, it is passed the address of the *pointer itself*. Notice that it is called with

```
Get_Text_Double(&name2)
```

which has an `&` address-of operator which the other 2 functions lack.

So here when you write to `*string` you are altering the value of the actual pointer `name2` itself, and not the memory it was allocated.

So `name2` will now point to your string literal `"test2"` and no text was copied. Now, you have changed the pointer, and you cannot pass its new value to `free` because you cannot `free` a string literal. You can only `free` the memory by using the pointer value originally returned by `malloc`, which you cannot do, because `name2` was overwitten.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on the second function? Why can't `name2` be free'd? I'm a little confused by that.

Comment: @MoMoe0 I have expanded my answer.

Comment: Oh okay! It makes a lot more sense now, so you can't free it because `name2` doesn't even know about the memory that was allocated before hand because it's value is pointing to the string literal instead, so it cannot be free'd. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can also rewrite this without functions:

```
char *name1 = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
char *name2 = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
char *name3 = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));

char *string1 = name1;
string1 = "t1";
printf("%s\n", name1);

char **string2 = &name2;
*string2 = "t2";
printf("%s\n", name2);

char *string3 = name3;
strcpy(string3, "t3");
printf("%s\n", name3);
```

In the first example `string1 = "t1"` means `string1` no longer points to `name1`. This will not change `name1`, so `name1` is still uninitialized and when you print `name1` it will show random characters.

In the second example we can rewrite `*string2 = "t2"` as `*(&name2) = "t2"`, and `*(&name2)` is just `name2`. This can be simplified to:

```
name2 = "t2";
```

Printing `name2` will show `"t2"` but now you cannot free the memory which was allocated with `malloc`

The third example is fills `name3` with `"t3"` and is fine.